# pymongo set read_preferences on connect via the config file

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

`ENVIRONMENT_CONFIG_FILE` contains :

```
MONGODB_SETTINGS = {
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': 27017,
    'db': 'my_db'
}

//in my application
app.config.from_envvar('ENVIRONMENT_CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION')

MongoEngine(app)
```

supposed I want to set `read_prefrences`, I can do it in the application level

```
from pymongo import ReadPreference
app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS']['read_prefrences'] = ReadPreference.PRIMARY
MongoEngine(app)
```

which will work, but I want to set the read_preferences in the config file. how do I do that since `ReadPreference.PRIMARY` is not a `string`?

Comment: In that case, you should set the configuration using an object. `from_object`.

Comment: Thanks, send as answer